# how to unfulfill a fulfilled promise in bluebird

Tags: bluebird

I have a situation where I stored an array of operations wrapped in a promise. Now, every time a request hits the API it executes this operations.

Let's say I have created a bunch of operations to get a status of running services:

```js
const jobs = [];

function statusRequest (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(error, resp, body) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

services.forEach(url => {
  jobs.push(statusRequest(url));
});

function handler (request, reply) {
  Promise.all(jobs).then(results => {
    // handle results
  })
  .catch(error => reply(error).code(500))
}

module.exports = {
 'auth'        : false,
 'description' : 'Get the status of all the services',
 'tags'        : [ 'api', 'system', 'status' ],

  handler
};
```

When a request hits the API handler for the 1st time it fetches the status and sets it fulfilment value to that result (cached). Succeeding requests to the API will have the first fulfilment value return.

Is there a way to reset the promise to unfulfilled so each call would just execute the operations already created?

Comment: 1. No. 2. That's an obvious XY problem: explain what you're trying to do, not how you try to do it and show your code that fails to do what you want.

Comment: Lets translate what you asked from DDD to English. "I don't want to do work every time I want something to happen. But I want that thing to happen." An Operation is a metaphor for work being done. The fulfillment of the `promise` is the "completion" of that piece of work.

Comment: Although it is technically possible (anything is possible in JS). It is the worst idea possible to do so. Because it does not make logical, grammatical or design sense. I promise you, the next developer to work on your code "He will look for you, he will find you, and he will kill you".

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to reset the promise to unfulfilled so each call would
>   just execute the operations already created?

No, you cannot do this.

To get access to the result of an existing promise, you don't need to unfulfill it (which is something you can't do anyway). You can just add a new `.then()` handler to it.

It sounds like you can just cache the original promise and use new `.then()` handlers on it.  This will then just return the previous result.  It's a simple way to do caching of async results.

```
var doSomeAPICall = (function() {
    var cachedPromise;

    return function() {
        if (!cachedPromise) {
            cachedPromise = doSomeAsyncOperation();
        }
        return cachedPromise;
    }
})();
```

And, sample usage:

```
doSomeAPICall().then(function(data) {
    // process data here
});

// the second time, it will be using a cached result
doSomeAPICall().then(function(data) {
    // process data here
});
```

Remember, you can always add more `.then()` handlers to an existing promise to get access to the result it will have or already has.

---

FYI, you can't unfulfill a promise.  Promises are purposely one-shot devices that latch their state once they are fulfilled or rejected.  You can add new `.then()` handlers to it to get access to the result of the promise or you can create a new promise if you want to execute a new async operation.  You don't reuse an existing promise to execute another async operation.  They are explicitly designed to prevent that.

---

If this isn't what you are trying to do, then please clarify your question some more so we can more clearly understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This seems to answer what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @James - Does this help answer your question?